# TIme.now and Created_At different formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

Ive noticed that in a model the `created_at` attribute when rendering a model to `json` has the format like:

```
2013-05-20T22:12:31Z
```

and calling `Time.now` and rendering to `json` gives a format like:

```
2013-05-21 00:04:03 +0000
```

I am trying to create a web service for an `iOS` app where I need to compare the current time vs the created time but cant do so because of the timezone difference.

What does the `Z` in the `Created_at` attribute represent? Is that a timezone? If so how do I change the `Time.now` timezone to match?

If `Z` is not a timezone, any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord Timestamp columns (like created_at and updated_at) are loaded as the type [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html), while Time.now produces a [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html).  These classes have different default to_s formats, which accounts for your discrepancy.

As you guessed, both the Z and the +0000 relate to the timezone of the datetime.  Your created at value is being expressed as an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date where Z means Zulu, another way of expressing the UTC or GMT 0-offset timezone.  Good news is that means both of your dates are already in UTC.

I'm not sure what your use case is, but you should consider doing this date comparison on the server if possible instead of in the iOS client.  In that case the string representation wouldn't matter since the underlying numerical values of the dates would be compared.

If you really need to do the comparison on the iOS client, then you need to explicitly format both date values when rendering the JSON so you will have a consistent representation.  You'll want to do a `created.strftime(...)` and `Time.now.strftime(...)` to format the values.  ISO 8601 is a good choice for date formats in an API, although you will probably want to check and see what's easiest to consume given the iOS libraries you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the problem I was experiencing is actually in my comparison code, but this is very useful information which will allow me to create a better comparison algorithm.